# Named parameter in update where clause (pdo object)

Tags: php

I try to translate this query to my `PDO object` from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9795742/what-is-the-best-method-to-make-sure-two-people-dont-edit-the-same-row-on-my-we):

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET col1 = <<new value>>,
       col2 = <<new values>>,
       last_modified_timestamp = <<new timestamp>>
 WHERE primary_key = <<key column>>
   AND last_modified_timestamp = <<last modified timestamp you originally queried>>
```

So i have a "modified" field in the mysql table and fetch the data (SELECT modified AS last_modified) to pre-fill in a hidden field in my form and post the value to the object:

```
$position->readOne();    
$position->last_modified = $_POST['last_modified'];    
    <input  name='last_modified' value='{$position->last_modified}'>
```

My object update query looks like:

```
UPDATE positions
SET 
... some values ...
WHERE id=:id
AND modified=:last_modified

$stmt->bindParam(":last_modified", $this->last_modified);
```

If I check the posted variables, everything looks fine but the update query ignores my second where clause completely and override the modified field after post the form.

Sure a beginner issue but I can´t find it.

Thanks

EDIT:
Select query

```
public function readOne(){

        $query = "SELECT 
        p.position,
        p.modified,
        p.modified AS last_modified
        FROM positions p
        WHERE id = ?
        LIMIT 0,1";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query );
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->id);
        $stmt->execute();

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

       $this->position = $row['position'];            
       $this->modified = $row['modified'];
       $this->last_modified = $row['last_modified'];

    }
```

Update query

```
 public function updatePosition(){
        $this->getTimestamp();

        $query = "UPDATE positions
                SET 
                position=:position,
                modified=:modified,
                WHERE id=:id
                AND modified=:last_modified";

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $this->position=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->position));

        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $this->id); 
        $stmt->bindParam(":position", $this->position);
        $stmt->bindParam(":modified", $this->timestamp);
        $stmt->bindParam(":last_modified", $this->last_modified);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            print_r($this->last_modified);
            return true;
        }
        print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
        return false;
    }
 public function getTimestamp(){
     date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
     $this->timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 }
```

Comment: How often do you use the placeholder `:last_modified`?

Comment: I use the placeholder only for this purpose in the code snippets above

Comment: what does it mean though, a "*second* WHERE clause"?

Comment: It is ok ... I will find out for myself. THANKS!

Comment: AND modified=:last_modified

Comment: Post the PHP code where you define your query.  There might be an error there, but you only posted the query, outside of PHP context.  Are you tried printing $position->last_modified to make sure it is set before using it?

Comment: I added the query code. Yes, the $position->last_modified is set before post the form.

Comment: Is it possible that the issue is related the "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" field in mysql? I tried different ways wo compare both values as UNIX_TIMESTAMP, DATE_FORMAT and also as strings but have no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The update query and everything else worked fine but the problem was the notification handling, so the function updatePosition() told me everything was updated but it worked as it should and it did not update anything if the value was not the same.

This fixed it:

```
if($stmt->execute()){
     $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
     if ($affected_rows == 1) {
          return true;
}
```

This helped me to understand how it works ... [PDOStatement::execute() returns true but the data is not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646319/pdostatementexecute-returns-true-but-the-data-is-not-updated#19646692)